# "Deshalb" am Ende des Nebensatzes

Tags: word-order

Folgendes ist aus dem Roman *Tschick* von Wolfgang Hernndorf:

> Und dann sah Tschick mich lange an und sagte, ich solle nicht glauben,
> dass Tatjana mich nicht eingeladen hätte, weil ich langweilig wäre,
> oder dass sie mich nicht mögen würde deshalb.

Ich würde erwarten, dass "deshalb" direkt vor "nicht" kommen würde. Ich dachte auf jeden Fall, dass das Verb am Ende des Nebensatzes stehen muss. Kann jemand die Position von "deshalb" erklären?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die zwei durch *oder* verbundenen *dass*-Sätze sind genau parallel konstruiert. In beiden Fällen gibt es ein ins [Nachfeld](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/2020) [ausgeklammertes](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/37) Satzglied. Im ersten Satz ist das ausgeklammerte Satzglied ein Nebensatz; dann ist Ausklammerung der erwartete Normalfall. Im zweiten Satz handelt es sich beim ausgeklammerten Satzglied dagegen um ein Adverb und die Ausklammerung hat eher mündlichen Charakter. Im gegebenen Fall könnte der Zweck der Ausklammerung im zweiten Satz sein, Parallelität herzustellen: denn so steht in beiden Fällen das auf den Grund verweisende Satzglied im Nachfeld.

| linke Klammer | Mittelfeld | rechte Klammer | Nachfeld |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dass | Tatjana mich nicht | eingeladen hätte | weil ich langweilig wäre |
| dass | sie mich nicht | mögen würde | deshalb |

Answer (score 3):

Der Satz ist grammatisch falsch, aber vermutlich versucht der Autor, durch bewußte Brüche die natürliche Sprache (die ja auch nicht immer frei von Brüchen ist) nachzuahmen.

Berühmtes Vorbild dafür ist etwa Georg Büchners "Woyzeck", dessen Autor dieses Stilmittel in einem (damals) aufsehenerregenden Bruch mit der Tradition einsetzte und "normale Umgangssprache" (im Falle Woyzecks und Maries sogar dialektartig gefärbt) auf die Theaterbühne brachte.

Ein anderes, wenigstens ebenso eindringliches, Beispiel ist Nestroy, der seine Figuren - etwas später als Büchner - ebenfalls in Floskeln der Umgangssprache sprechen läßt, und damit die unerlebte Floskelhaftigkeit des Gesprochenen deutlich macht. Zwei Beispiele aus dem *Lumpazivagabundus*:

> Das Kraut und die Ruben hauetens durcheinand' als wie das Kraut und die Ruben

oder

> Wahrlich, wenn ich mein' Verdruß ned versaufen tät', ich müßt' mich aus Verzweiflung schier der Trunksucht ergeben.